# dtype placement

Tags: python

I am new to python and was creating this line to try and get the result (but facing problems)

[[12. 14. 16. 18.]
[26. 28. 30. 32.]]

I think the problem is with the dtype? Could you guys give me some rope? Thanks!

y = np.arange(([12,20,2], [26,34,2]), dtype=float)

Comment: Since you want an array and not a range of scalars, you want `y = np.array(([12,20,2], [26,34,2]), dtype=float)`

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import numpy as np

np.array((np.arange(12,20,2), np.arange(26,34,2)), dtype=float)
```

Returns

```
array([[12., 14., 16., 18.],
       [26., 28., 30., 32.]])
```